# Cargar datos con Ajax a fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando con un Plugin de Jquery llamado FullCalendar y pretendo enviar los eventos desde una llamada ajax pero soy super novato con el, tengo el siguiente código:

HTML:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-09-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: 
               [
                    {
                        "start": "2017-10-20 07:00:00",
                        "title": "Work"
                    }
               ]


        });

    });
```

Pero en lugar de tener los eventos estaticos, quiero algo como el ejemplo siguiente, que encontré en internet, pero en realidad no sé porque no me funciona:

Ejemplo de envio de datos:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-09-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'work-events.json',
                    type: "GET",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function (doc) {
                        var events = [];
                        if ($(doc) != undefined && $(doc).Events.length > 0) {
                            $(doc).Events.forEach(function (entry) {
                                events.push({
                                    title: entry.Title,
                                    start: entry.Start,
                                    className: entry.className
                                });

                            });
                        }
                        callback(events);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert('Error in fetching data');
                    }
                });
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                alert(calEvent.title);
            }


        });

    });
```

al momento de correrlo, me manda el alert de error:

> alert('Error in fetching data');

este es mi archivo JSON:

```
[
  {
    "start": "2016-01-02 07:00:00",
    "title": "Work",
    "className": "Work",
    "allDay": "FALSE"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-01-02 08:00:00",
    "title": "Work",
    "className": "Work",
    "allDay": "FALSE"
  },
  {
    "start": "2016-01-02 09:00:00",
    "title": "Work",
    "className": "Work",
    "allDay": "FALSE"
  }
]
```

es mucho más grande, pero para que sepan que es lo que tengo, todo el archivo tiene la misma estructura, ya lo intente manualmente y si me pinta todos los eventos, así que no es error del JSON.

Comment: Puede ser porque por el uppercase de las variables: de acuerdo con el JSON que colocas, es `title` no `Title`; lo mismo con `start`.

Comment: En realidad en events hay todo una función con lógica de procesamiento que tu no estas poniendo

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, ya intente cambiandolos y en me da el mismo error.

Comment: @abrahamhs, a que te refieres con que, yo no estoy poniendo, disculpa, soy nuevo y me gustaria que me ayudaras a como realizarlo, gracias.

Comment: `....function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({....`

Comment: @Roger, me refería esta línea: `title: entry.Title`; ¿probaste? `title: entry.title` - fíjate en que `title` está en minúscula.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, si, ya lo realize de esa forma pero no funciona.

Comment: @abrahamhs, si sé a que te refieres con la lógica de programación, pero no sé porque me dices que no estoy poniendo, y si es así, de que forma lo podría hacer?

Comment: Esta parte es un array `events.push({
                                    title: entry.Title,
                                    start: entry.Start,
                                    className: entry.className
                                });` pero tu le estas mandando un json `[
                    {
                        "start": "2017-10-20 07:00:00",
                        "title": "Work"
                    }
               ]` eso es lo que yo veo

Comment: @abrahamhs, ya comprendí lo que me dices, pero  ¿entonces como podría mandar el JSON?.

Comment: no tienes que enviar un json, sino un array

Comment: amigo una reguntade donde sale tu variable Events