# Agregar indice a array asociativo en php

Tags: php, array

Estoy creando un array asociativo a través de php después de hacer una validación de datos, dicho código es para hacer funcionar la librería "fullcalendar" . Sin embargo, al terminar esa validación necesito hacer una segunda validación para agregar otro índice, pero por alguna razón este índice me queda fuera ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?, no logro encontrar el inconveniente.

Mi código:

```
foreach ($this->eventos as $key => $value) {
    if($value['allDay']==1){
        $evts[]= array('id' => base64_encode(tools::my_encrypt($value['id'])),
            'title' => $value['titulo'],
            'start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['inicio_fecha'])),
            'end' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['fin_fecha'])),
            'allDay' => true,
            'color' => self::getColor($value['tipo_evento']),

        );
    }
    if($this->tipo == $value['tipo_usuario']){
        array_push($evts, array ('tipo' =>'check-circle-o') );
    }
}
```

Me estoy basando en estos dos ejemplos:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285716/add-font-awesome-icon-to-full-calendar-title

[Cargar datos con Ajax a fullcalendar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110495/cargar-datos-con-ajax-a-fullcalendar)

En resumen:
El código crea el json para que el plugin fullcalendar lo lea correctamente. Cuando un evento en el calendario corresponde al usuario que lo está visualizando le agrega un icono. (O por lo menos esa es la idea.)

El problema:
Me está agregando como si fuera otro índice de esta menera (ver el final del código):

{"id":"WVRoV2EzaEhkVlF6ZVUwOWZIeDhoVWZPaEtzRGUvaz0=","title":"neftali 2","start":"2018-11-23","end":"1969-12-31","allDay":true,"color":"#ff6258"},**{"tipo":"check-circle-o"}**,

Yo necesito que se cree de esta manera:

{"id":"WVRoV2EzaEhkVlF6ZVUwOWZIeDhoVWZPaEtzRGUvaz0=","title":"neftali 2","start":"2018-11-23","end":"1969-12-31","allDay":true,"color":"#ff6258",**"tipo":"check-circle-o"**},

Como queda (separado por llaves):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como debería quedar (separado por "," dentro de la misma llave):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojalá me puedan compartir una pista, la verdad estoy liado.

Gracias, saludos.

Comment: En vez de esto: `array_push($evts, array ('color' =>'check-circle-o') );`, debería ser algo así: **`$evts['color']='check-circle-o';`**, pero ya tienes un índice llamado `color` antes: `'color' => self::getColor($value['tipo_evento']),`  ... no puedes tener dos claves con el mismo nombre, ¿no hay algo mal planteado en tu lógica?

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón, fue error de dedo. El indique que deseo agregar se llama "tipo". Realizando los cambios que sugieres queda de la siguiente manera http://prntscr.com/lk9o0t tampoco me funciona :/

Comment: Es evidente que entonces debes poner el código así: `$evts[]['tipo']='check-circle-o';`. Pero todavía no comprendo en qué casos quieres agregar ese índice, si en todos los casos o solamente en caso de que el segundo `if` se cumpla.

Comment: Exacto, solo si segundo if se cumple, debería agregarse esa clave, algo así mira: http://prntscr.com/lka6ic  date cuenta que la primera línea tiene el valor y la segunda no (he agregado esos valores automáticamente). Siguiendo tu sugerencia me sigue haciendo lo mismo  mira: http://prntscr.com/lka70l (No se si alcanzas a notar que el índice está separado por comas y entre llaves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Si quieres agregar una nueva clave dentro del primer `if`, la puedes agregar tal y como haces con las otras</s>:

```
if($value['allDay']==1){
    $evts[]= array('id' => base64_encode(tools::my_encrypt($value['id'])),
        'title' => $value['titulo'],
        'start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['inicio_fecha'])),
        'end' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['fin_fecha'])),
        'allDay' => true,
        'color' => self::getColor($value['tipo_evento']),
        'tipo' => 'check-circle-o'

    );
}
```

En cambio, si quieres agregarla sólo cuando se cumpla el segundo `if`, entonces puedes implementar un contador para saber en qué posición de array agregar la nueva clave:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($this->eventos as $key => $value) {
    if($value['allDay']==1){
        $evts[]= array('id' => base64_encode(tools::my_encrypt($value['id'])),
            'title' => $value['titulo'],
            'start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['inicio_fecha'])),
            'end' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['fin_fecha'])),
            'allDay' => true,
            'color' => self::getColor($value['tipo_evento']),

        );
    }
    if($this->tipo == $value['tipo_usuario']){
        $evts[$i]['tipo']='check-circle-o';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Así debería funcionar.

Comment: El indice "tipo" solo se debe de agregar si se cumple la segunda condición. Es decir, se debe de sumar a los índices previamente cargados. Siguiendo tu sugerencia continuo con el inconveniente, el valor se agrega en llaves separadas mira: https://prnt.sc/lka70l  y lo que busco es algo así: https://prnt.sc/lka6ic  (En este segundo enlace he agregados los datos manualmente)

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta puedes tener un contador y usarlo como clave. Por ejemplo, fuera del bucle: `$i=0;`.  Y dentro del bucle, agregas así: `if($this->tipo == $value['tipo_usuario']){
    $evts[$i]['tipo']='check-circle-o';
}  $i++;`  Debes incrementar el contador dentro del bucle `for`, pero fuera de los dos `if`.

Comment: ¡¡¡¡¡¡¡Excelente!!!!!!!! ¿Me creerás que no he dormido intentando solucionar esto? :( 9:25am CDMX, me acabas de salvar la existencia. ¿Cómo no se me ocurrió antes?   PFFF, gracias infinitas @A. Cedano quedó resuelto.

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta me alegro de que se haya solucionado. Saludos y... haber preguntado antes, seguro que alguien habría respondido.